# How to override all methods matching regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I got a class and a module (names are changed for security issues)

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Identifier
  ...
end

module Identifier
  def self.included base
    base.instance_eval do

    def find(*args)
      #new find implementation
    end
  end
end
```

**The aim:**
 I've already re-written find method to be able to search by other than ids, but I also need to override every association setter methods in the original class.

Sample:

```
def child_model_id=(value)
  #body of the override method
end
```

*Disclaimer: I'm aware that this is hacky and evil in general, but this is a legacy project and I got no other way around.*

Is there a way to override all methods of the original class ending with **"_id="** from the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this inside your new class:

```
OldClass.instance_methods(false).grep(/_id=?$/).each do |method|
    define_method method do
        # Do what you want in the new method depending upon the method name
        case method
        when 'child_model_id='
           # Do this one
        when 'foo_id'
           # Do that one
        ...
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get instance methods of a class by calling, well, `instance_methods`.

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end

  def bar_id
  end

  instance_methods(false).grep(/.+_id=$/) # => [:bar_id]
  #                 ^^ get only own methods (not inherited object_id, for example)
end
```

The rest you already know.